# kotlinで曜日を詳しく取得

Tags: kotlin

kotlinで"その月の何回目の水曜日"などをアプリ側から指定して取得する方法を模索しております

Comment: もう少し不明点を書いた方が、回答が得られると思います。西暦1年1月1日は何曜日かご存じですか？うるう年は何年ごとにあるかご存じですか？このあたりがわかれば計算方法はわかると思います。グレゴリオ暦で調べてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

[`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) ([チュートリアル](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/adjusters.html)) を実装することになるかと思います。

質問文の例であれば、組み込みで [`TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth(int,java.time.DayOfWeek))というメソッドが提供されているのでこれを利用できると思います。

```kotlin
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters

fun main() {
    val base = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 3)
    val date = base.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY))
    println(date) // 2021-12-08
}
```